# md-autocomplete template with ng-click cannot prevent selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to place a button inside an md-item-template of md-autocomplete to invoke some action.

Problem: I cannot prevent the selection of the item. `$event.preventDefault();` is not working and the documentation has no hint either.

My target is to allow either the (normal) selection of a suggestion or when you click the button, the text from this suggestion should be copied to the searchbox. In the second case the user can now continue to write to further narrow down his search. Google has this feature on its mobile search to allow the user to narrow down the search without writing all of it and i want to have this feature in my app.

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="nvSearchCtrl.selectedItem"
             md-search-text="nvSearchCtrl.unfinishedParticle"
             md-items="item in nvSearchCtrl.querySearch(nvSearchCtrl.unfinishedParticle)"
             md-item-text="item.name">
<md-item-template>
    <div layout="row">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <md-button ng-click="$event.preventDefault();nvSearchCtrl.unfinishedParticle=item.name;"
                   class="md-icon-button">
            <md-icon>call_made</md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </div>
</md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

**I have prepared a fiddle showing the error: https://jsfiddle.net/4509c87b/**

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for it please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4509c87b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem.Added a new directive stop-event to the snippet below.

### Done by using the angular directives

```
.directive('stopEvent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    };
 });
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4509c87b/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) (so that the click event doesn't continue to bubble up the dom to also trigger the selection) instead of `event.preventDefault()`.